# VSCode eslint does not pickup tsconfig paths

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tsconfig

VSCode linting does not seem to respect the paths I defined in my tsconfig.json file.

I get the following error, when importing anything from an "alias" defined in my tsconfig.json.

[image]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "esNext",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7", "es2017", "dom"],
    "types": ["react", "jest", "node"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./src/*"],
      "common/*": ["src/common/*"],
      "test/*": ["test/*"],
      "test-utils": ["test/test-utils.tsx"],
      "static/*": ["static/*"],
      "storybook/*": [".storybook/*"]
    },
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": ["__root/src/**/*", "src/typings.d.ts", "./@types", ".storybook/decorators/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": ["react-app"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

package versions:

```
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.3.0",
"babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
"eslint": "7.10.0",
"eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.3.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.4",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.21.2",
```

.prettierrc

```
{
    "printWidth": 100,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "useTabs": false,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "arrowParens": "avoid"
}
```

I have been looking for a solution I haven't tried for hours, but I'm not finding anything specifically related to local modules and tsconfig path aliases.

(The code works and builds just fine, it is only a linting problem I'm seeing in VScode)

I have the `tslint` package installed in VSCode. I have tried removing this and replacing it with `eslint` but that did not make any difference.

Comment: https://medium.com/@davidmieloch/tilde-paths-with-eslint-typescript-and-webpack-971f694c9b15, did you try adding a resolver map  for ~ to your src folder?

Comment: @SenguptaAmit just tried it, that didn't work either. But also I don't want to have to maintain my aliases in multiple places.

Comment: Have a look at [Crisp React](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/tree/master/client) project, it uses eslint with TypeScript [Path Mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) feature and therefore has the `paths` setting in `tsconfig.json`. As the first troubleshooting step I'd recommend to ensure the standalone eslint (invoked via `scripts` section of `package.json`) e.g. `yarn lint` doesn't choke on `paths`. The second step would be to ensure VS Code and eslint integration picks it up.

Comment: @MLyck did you find any solution?